# Create a stand-alone MS Graph login portal

Tags: php, asp.net, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking to create a stand-alone login portal (using asp.net) for MS Graph, however all the documentation I can find tries to force me to link each portal to a particular registered app in Azure (which is defeating the purpose I had in mind).  The main reason for doing this is that I have 3 PHP sites which currently utilise their own username/password login and I want to standardise them all and connect to Azure as a SSO without making any changes to PHP (apart from setting up a redirect)  Hopefully the following scenario makes sense:

1) I create a stand-alone portal using asp.net that contains all the logic for connecting to Azure using MS Graph - I have 1 Client ID that I connect to (thus when any app connects, it is treated as 1 application and fulfils the view of SSO).

2) If User A connects to PHP site 1, they should then be redirected to the new login site to enter their Azure credentials.  If successful, they should be redirected to the home page of PHP site 1 as a logged in user.

3) If User A then connects to PHP site 2, it should be able to detect that a token has already been assigned when they logged into site 1 and do a 'silent' token request (without prompting them to enter credentials again) and redirect them to the home page of site 2.

Due to the masses of different information available on the various MS sites, it is pretty difficult to find what I need.  In my initial testing, when I have setup a test project (asp.net MVC) I can only assign 1 redirect URL, however the redirect needs to be custom (based on which PHP site the request comes from).

Hopefully this makes sense to someone and knows of something that might be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to centralize Azure AD authentication trough your MVC application and supposing you'r using the authorization code flow you can:

1. Make each PHP site call your MVC app including its id or base url. 
   E.G: `https://myapp/login?site-id=1`
2. Make your MVC app include the passed id or url in the [Azure AD authorization request "state" parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code).
    E.G: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state={php site id or url}&...`.
    
   This value will be returned in the authorizaton code response handled by your MVC app callback endpoint. 
   E.G: `https://myapp/callback?code={code}&state={php site id or url}&...`
3. Use the state and redirect to your PHP site.

If you need help with a specific authentication middleware please share some code.

Comment: Thanks Alfredo.  After a small internal discussion the original dev of the PHP sites decided to try to integrate directly with MS Graph and was successful, so I no longer have a need to create a backend authentication site.  Your advice is food for thought though - I might use it in the future.

Comment: @ChrisMason Anytime!